# oddity generating CSV from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

A script to dump the contents of a table into a csv file and send it as an email attachment.  it all works, until I add the 'note_text' field in to the array.  there's a little over 60,000 rows in the table, and its all fine until I add the notes text at which point it runs and gets to the 'emailing now' line then hangs. The note_text field definition in the table is 'text' as opposed to varchar, could that be the problem?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", “*****”, “*****”, “****”);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//grab all rows from the table 
 
$query = "SELECT ID, job_ID, note_date, note_author, note_text, flagged, FAO, time,     category FROM funeral_job_notes";
 
//loop the fetch and concactenate into string
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        
    $data[] = array('ID', 'job_ID', 'note_date', 'note_author', 'note_text',    'flagged', 'FAO', 'time', 'category');
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = array($row['ID'],$row['job_ID'],$row['note_date'],$row['note_author'],$row['note_text'],$row['flagged'],$row['FAO'],$row['time'],$row['category']);
    }
    $result->free();
}

function create_csv_string($data2) {
    if (!$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+')) return FALSE;

    foreach ($data2 as $line) fputcsv($fp, $line);

    rewind($fp);

    return stream_get_contents($fp);
}

function send_csv_mail ($csvData, $body, $to = 'me@me.com',  $from = 'server@me.com',$subject = 'notes backup' ) {
    $multipartSep = '-----'.md5(time()).'-----';

    $headers = array(
        "From: $from",
        "Reply-To: $from",
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$multipartSep\""
    );

    // Make the attachment
 
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(create_csv_string($csvData))); 

    // Make the body of the message
    $body = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
          . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed\r\n"
          . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
          . "\r\n"
          . "$body\r\n"
          . "--$multipartSep\r\n"
          . "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n"
          . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
          . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"AFILE.csv\"\r\n"
          . "\r\n"
          . "$attachment\r\n"
          . "--$multipartSep--";

    // Send the email, return the result
    return @mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers)); 

}

echo "emaling now <br>";
$resp=send_csv_mail($data,  "job notes backup");

if( $resp ){
    echo "Mail sent <br>" ;
} else {
    echo "Mail not sent <br>";
}
echo “all done <br>";

?>
```

Comment: Hangs while creating the CSV or sending the email? If it's the email, then maybe huge attachments aren't allowed to be sent by your email service provider? You could rather push it to some object storage and then attach the link in the email.

Comment: If you remove the error suppression do you get an error?

Comment: This is a bit of a mess. You should indent each control block with something consistent, tabs, 5 spaces, 4 spaces, etc. You should define functions at the end or the beginning of code, not in the middle (IMO at the end).

Comment: This could be a copy/paste issue, but you have a few smart quotes throughout the script that completely break it

Comment: no attachment limits at the server - dumping the table to csv through Navicat creates a file about 7.5mb, so not stupidly large.  

Nothing in the error log and yes, copy and pasting the code in made it somewhat messy.  

most of the note_text fields are <255 chars, but there are a few that are bigger, but not massively so

Comment: Debug within the functions to see where it gets to with a bit more precision. Also do you have error logging enabled? Also why are you suppressing errors using @? That merely hinders debugging.